# Adding some text to php code -- for dummies

Tags: php

Thanks in advance for reading this.

I know nothing about php or coding, and I've been trying to follow some internet guides to add a few words of text to a snippet of code. The code is used to do some automatic currency conversions, and that's embedded in an article which is opened in a popup.

I'm desperately trying to add a few words in front of each separate conversion. I've added the code below -- the output is the last three lines, and I'd like to add some text in front of each line (different text for each line), but I keep running into trouble, I just can't seem to get it right.

I would greatly appreciate any ideas, I'm not actually even sure it's possible.

I'd like to add something in front of each of those last three lines.

Is that possible? I would appreciate any and all ideas, thanks in advance for your time.

Best wishes,
Ben

```
 <?php
// #########################################################################
// September 09, 2012
// Real time PHP currency converter function with quotes from Yahoo Finance
// Written by Leonard Whistler
// lwhistler@gmail.com
// #########################################################################

function currencyExchange($amount,$baseCurrency,$quoteCurrency) {
$open = fopen("http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=$baseCurrency[0]$quoteCurrency[0]=X&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv", "r");
$exchangeRate = fread($open, 2000);
fclose($open);
$exchangeRate = str_replace("\"", "", $exchangeRate);
$exchangeRate = explode(",", $exchangeRate);
$results = ($exchangeRate[1]*$amount);
$results = number_format ($results, 0);
$amount = number_format ($amount);
$timeStamp = date('F d, Y');
$timeStamp = "$timeStamp $exchangeRate[3]";

echo "$amount $baseCurrency[1] = $results $quoteCurrency[1]<br>";
$timestamp;
}

// for additional currency ticker symbols visit: http://finance.yahoo.com/currency-converter
$usd = array('USD','USD');
$eur = array('EUR','Euro');
$jpy = array('JPY','Japanese Yen');
$gbp = array('GBP','British Pounds');
$aud = array('AUD','Australian Dollars');
$chf = array('CHF','Swiss Francs');
$cad = array('CAD','Canadian Dollars');
$krw = array('KRW','KRW');

// amount, base currency, quote currency.
currencyExchange("25",$usd,$krw);
currencyExchange("20",$usd,$krw);
currencyExchange("39",$usd,$krw);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
// #########################################################################
// September 09, 2012
// Real time PHP currency converter function with quotes from Yahoo Finance
// Written by Leonard Whistler
// lwhistler@gmail.com
// #########################################################################

function currencyExchange($pre,$amount,$baseCurrency,$quoteCurrency) {
$open = fopen("http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=$baseCurrency[0]$quoteCurrency[0]=X&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv", "r");
$exchangeRate = fread($open, 2000);
fclose($open);
$exchangeRate = str_replace("\"", "", $exchangeRate);
$exchangeRate = explode(",", $exchangeRate);
$results = ($exchangeRate[1]*$amount);
$results = number_format ($results, 0);
$amount = number_format ($amount);
$timeStamp = date('F d, Y');
$timeStamp = "$timeStamp $exchangeRate[3]";

echo "$pre $amount $baseCurrency[1] = $results $quoteCurrency[1]<br>";
$timestamp;
}

// for additional currency ticker symbols visit: http://finance.yahoo.com/currency-converter
$usd = array('USD','USD');
$eur = array('EUR','Euro');
$jpy = array('JPY','Japanese Yen');
$gbp = array('GBP','British Pounds');
$aud = array('AUD','Australian Dollars');
$chf = array('CHF','Swiss Francs');
$cad = array('CAD','Canadian Dollars');
$krw = array('KRW','KRW');

// amount, base currency, quote currency.
currencyExchange("whatever","25",$usd,$krw);
currencyExchange("somethingelse","20",$usd,$krw);
currencyExchange("blabla","39",$usd,$krw);

?>
```

Comment: Seems a bit redundant to pass it through to the function when you can just do an `echo "whatever"; currencyExchange("25",$usd,$krw);`. Might make more sense to return the result rather then echo it in the function: `echo "whatever " . currencyExchange("25",$usd,$krw);`

Comment: That would need some more changes... currencyExchange echoes the answer, so in this case your suggestion would print "whatever" behind the code, not in front of it...

Comment: And I assume the `$timestamp` is what he wants to add to the output.

Comment: if it's $timestamp he wants to be printed change the echo to echo "$timestamp $amount $baseCurrency[1] = $results $quoteCurrency[1]<br>"; and remove the '$timestamp' on the line after it

Answer (score 0):

Although the last three lines invoke the currency conversion, the output is actually all done on this line:

```
echo "$amount $baseCurrency[1] = $results $quoteCurrency[1]<br>";
```

You can add any text you want to the start of that line, and it will be reflected in the output for each conversion. For example:

```
echo "Look some extra text $amount $baseCurrency[1] = $results $quoteCurrency[1]<br>";
```

What's happening is each of the last three lines runs the function currencyExchance(). That function prints output using the [echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) command. The echo command just outputs text (you put it in quotes) or php variables.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to change the output to include some text in front the function currencyExchange 's output is at the bottom as such:

```
echo "$amount $baseCurrency[1] = $results $quoteCurrency[1]<br>";
```

so you can add those words to that and everytime you call currencyExchange it'll add those words

```
echo "Some Extra Words $amount $baseCurrency[1] = $results $quoteCurrency[1]<br>";
```

Or modify the method to accept a variable 3 words like @patrick suggested before I could hit post. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your function immediately echo's the result, which is IMHO not ideal. So, instead of introducing a fourth parameter I would do the following.

```
<?php
// #########################################################################
// September 09, 2012
// Real time PHP currency converter function with quotes from Yahoo Finance
// Written by Leonard Whistler
// lwhistler@gmail.com
// #########################################################################

function currencyExchange($amount,$baseCurrency,$quoteCurrency) {
$open = fopen("http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=$baseCurrency[0]$quoteCurrency[0]=X&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv", "r");
$exchangeRate = fread($open, 2000);
fclose($open);
$exchangeRate = str_replace("\"", "", $exchangeRate);
$exchangeRate = explode(",", $exchangeRate);
$results = ($exchangeRate[1]*$amount);
$results = number_format ($results, 0);
$amount = number_format ($amount);
$timeStamp = date('F d, Y');
$timeStamp = "$timeStamp $exchangeRate[3]";

return "$amount $baseCurrency[1] = $results $quoteCurrency[1]";
$timestamp;
}

// for additional currency ticker symbols visit: http://finance.yahoo.com/currency-converter
$usd = array('USD','USD');
$eur = array('EUR','Euro');
$jpy = array('JPY','Japanese Yen');
$gbp = array('GBP','British Pounds');
$aud = array('AUD','Australian Dollars');
$chf = array('CHF','Swiss Francs');
$cad = array('CAD','Canadian Dollars');
$krw = array('KRW','KRW');

// amount, base currency, quote currency.
echo "the result is ".currencyExchange("25",$usd,$krw);
echo "Blabla ".currencyExchange("20",$usd,$krw);
echo "TEST: ".currencyExchange("39",$usd,$krw);

?>
```

This allows you to be more flexible with the output, e.g. wrapping the result in a table.

```
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><td>first request </td><td>".currencyExchange("25",$usd,$krw)."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>next</td><td>".currencyExchange("20",$usd,$krw)."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>and so</td><td>".currencyExchange("39",$usd,$krw)."</td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

I think one should separate the functions purpose from what you do with the result.